# What's the difference between xmpp.protocol.Message and xmpp.Message?

Tags: python, xmpp, xmpppy

What's the difference between xmpp.protocol.Message and xmpp.Message? I've used xmpp.Message and it works as expected, but I don't know how to send html messages using it.

I found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310750/sending-xhtml-over-jabber-using-xmpppy) for sending html messages using xmpp.protocol.Message, but, in my case, it's not sending message at all. It will be greatly helpful if I know how to send html message using xmpp.Message.

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [source code](http://xmpppy.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/xmpppy/xmpppy/xmpp/__init__.py?revision=1.9&view=markup) for `xmpp` includes this line:

```
from protocol import *
```

This means that there is no difference between `xmpp.Message` and `xmpp.protocol.Message` - they are the same class. You can verify this by looking at: `xmpp.Message is xmpp.protocol.Message` - it will be True.